# Unable to migrate error free from WSO2 AM 3.0.0 to 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm unable to migrate WSO2am 3.0.0 to 4.1.0 . I've been following the wso2 docs https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/300-to-410/upgrading-from-300-to-410/ . When running Step4.4 I get the following errors:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent} - Error while initializing the API manager component org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while saving tenant conf to the registry of tenant carbon.super
 
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIMgtDAOException: Failed to retrieve TENANT Configuration for org: carbon.super
 
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apim_db.AM_SYSTEM_CONFIGS' doesn't exist
 
ERROR {org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader} - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/api/am/admin]} - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} - One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
 
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} - Context [/api/am/admin] startup failed due to previous errors
 
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - Cannot stop context org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/admin]] in state [DESTROYED]
 
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - Webapp StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/admin] failed to deploy
 
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[api#am#admin.war].File[/wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#admin.war] org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Webapp failed to deploy, Lifecycle state is STOPPED

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer} - Error occurred while deploying webapp : /wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#admin.war org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[api#am#admin.war].File[/wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#admin.war]

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Webapp failed to deploy, Lifecycle state is STOPPED

ERROR {org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader} - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/api/am/devops/v0]} - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} - One or more listeners failed to start.

ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} - Context [/api/am/devops/v0] startup failed due to previous errors

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - Cannot stop context org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/devops/v0]] in state [DESTROYED]

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - Webapp StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/devops/v0] failed to deploy

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[api#am#devops#v0.war].File[/wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#devops#v0.war] org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer} - Error occurred while deploying webapp : /wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#devops#v0.war org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[api#am#devops#v0.war].File[/wso2/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#devops#v0.war]

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Webapp failed to deploy, Lifecycle state is STOPPED

ERROR {org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader} - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/api/am/devportal]} - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'AuthenticationInterceptor' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuthenticationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and many such repeated errors.

I'm using the product in a VM(amazon linux) and mysql(amazon RDS) in a single node.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the latest U2 level of APIM 4.1.0 for migration since it contains some changes that are required for the migration. Those changes are not available in the GA release (downloaded from website or github).

If you have a WSO2 subscription, you can update 4.1.0 to latest version using the U2 tool[1].

[1] - https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/overview/

Comment: We've been using the free version of 3.0.0 . Is there a way we can do it without the subscription, as we've to do this for an existing client. Or else upto what level can we upgrade for free?

Comment: You should be able to update to 4.0.0 without any issues. 4.1.0 related changes are not available publicly yet.